# how to get style cop to ignore a specific instance of a violation

Tags: c#, stylecop

I have a few instances in my code where Style cop gives out that:

"SA1119: The line contains unnecessary parenthesis."

Now I totally agree with this if I have a line of code that says:

```
int someValue = (((12 + 3) + 5));
```

However when I have something more complicated like:

```
textXpos = ((((float)this.Width - imageoffset) - textsize.Width) / 2);
```

I understand that I can rewrite this like:

```
textXpos = (((float)this.Width - imageoffset - textsize.Width) / 2);
```

And It will evaluate out to the same values, but I find the first one easier to read.  Is there a way to tell styecop to ignore this instance of the error?

Or do I need to work around this by assigning some of the equation to temp variables?

I don't want to wrap this code in an autogenerated region as I do want style cop to evaluate this section of code.

Thanks

---

Based on the suggestion by ken2k I tried the following:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
```

.
.
.

```
[SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.MaintainabilityRules", "SA1119:StatementMustNotUseUnnecessaryParenthesis", Justification = "Better for readability.")]
    public int Testmethod()
    {
        int returnValue = (((5 - 5) - 5) / 2);
        return returnValue;
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect?  Am I missing something?

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the following statement before the header of your method:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.MaintainabilityRules", "SA1119:StatementMustNotUseUnnecessaryParenthesis", Justification = "Better for readability.")]
```

But warnings SA1119 will be ignored for the whole method.

*EDIT*: at least remove the first and last parenthesis:

```
textXpos = (((float)this.Width - imageoffset) - textsize.Width) / 2;
```

Comment: It never occurred to me that it might be giving out about the outside parenthesis!! D'oh

Comment: Yes, I've the same problem here. I thought Stylecop team got rid of "Microsoft" string, but apparently not. See updated answer.

Comment: Ah your answer was much better than mine that "There is a bug in StyleCop 4.3 and I needed to upgrade to 4.4. Thanks.

Comment: Guys, the latest stable StyleCop version is 4.6. And there is experimental 4.7 that works with latest ReSharper. And for both of them you should suppress messages with "StyleCop..." instead of "Microsoft.StyleCop..." indeed.